# Add columns to a text file with set spacing in Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

I am setting up a malware zone file in DNS which will point all hosts to a specific IP. The file is simply a list of hostnames. This is what I have now:

```
googlle.in                               
greensny.com                  
hoefra.at                    
hotel-sas.ru
```

This is what I need it to look like:

```
googlle.in                IN           A          192.168.100.10                      
greensny.com              IN           A          192.168.100.10     
hoefra.at                 IN           A          192.168.100.10   
hotel-sas.ru              IN           A          192.168.100.10
```

I was able to throw something together with sed:

```
sed -i 's/$/                     IN          A           192.168.155.128/' db.malware-host-only
```

Which works, however it looks like this:

```
vururyuzeifadesi.net   IN          A           192.168.155.128
waseemamrohi.com   IN          A           192.168.155.128
weblab-srv.biz  IN          A           192.168.155.128
weghost.ru   IN          A           192.168.155.128
wnctnr.com   IN          A           192.168.155.128
```

How can I clean it up and have equal spacing between the columns so that the "IN" starts at a specific point with the "A" and the IP address columns also being equal distance apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{ printf "%-30s%10s%10s%20s\n",$1,"IN","A","192.168.100.10"; }' file
```

Comment: This worked great. Although I had to redirect output to a temp file. Can you explain exactly what the variables after printf mean and what they do?

Answer (score 5):

Just pipe the output to `column -t`:

```
sed 's/$/ IN A 192.168.155.128/' db.malware-host-only | column -t > tmp
mv tmp db.malware-host-only
```

You can use the `-o` parameter to extend the spaces between columns:

```
column -t -o '      '
```

You can't use `sed -i` with that, so output to a temp file, then rename it to the original name.

Comment: I'm dealing with over 25k hostnames, so your answer, while it may work, would not be practical. Could I use your example without the leading echo?

Comment: @user53029: Of course. Just specify the file name as the last parameter for `sed`.

Comment: This does not work. I am running sed 's/$/ IN A 192.168.155.128/' | column -t db.malware-host-only > db.malware-host-only-2 and it just hangs. When I kill it, it creates the file but there are no changes.

Comment: @user53029: Don't specify any filename for `column`, it operates on the output of `sed`: `sed 's/$/ IN A 192.168.155.128/' | column -t > db.malware-host-only-2`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was never able to get it to work. I'll have to go with Dennis's answer.

Comment: @user53029: Updated. Could you at least try?

Comment: Yes, will give it a shot. Thanks for updating your answer.